# "No reducer provided for key X" console.error in redux jest test

Tags: typescript, redux, jestjs

I have a reducer test that is passing but throwing out this weird error at the end:

```
console.error node_modules/redux/lib/utils/warning.js:14
    No reducer provided for key "newProducts"
```

**src/reducer/index.ts**

```
import newLineItemReducer from "./newLineItemReducer";
import renewedLineItemReducer from "./renewedLineItemReducer";

export interface LineItemState{
  renewedProducts: LineItem[]
  newProducts: LineItem[]
}

//used by both reducers
export interface LineItem{ 
  ...
}

// used by both "new" and "renewed" slice reducers
export function sharedFunction1() {
  ...
}

export default combineReducers<LineItemState>({
  renewedProducts: renewedLineItemReducer,
  newProducts: newLineItemReducer
});
```

**src/reducer/newLineItemReducer.ts**

```
import {LineItem, sharedFunction1 } from "./";

type Action = ...;
const newLineItemReducer =
  (state: LineItem[] = [], action: Action): LineItem[] => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ...:
      sharedFunction1(state, action.foo);
  }
}
export default newLineItemReducer;
```

**test/newLineItemReducer.spec.ts**

```
import newLineItemReducer from "@src/reducers/newLineItemReducer";
test("foo", () => {
   let state = //
   let action = //
   const updatedState = newLineItemReducer(state, action);
   ...
});
```

The weird thing is there is no code that is actually calling the root reducer from index.  My test is directly calling the slice "newLineItemReducer".  Seems like just the act of importing the shared interface and case function from `reducer/index.ts` is causing the issue (If I remove `combineReducer` export there is no error)?

Comment: My guess is that you've faced a problem with circular imports, when two files import each other. `newLineItemReducer.ts` imports `index.ts` which once again imports `newLineItemReducer.ts`. Depending on the module loader you might get an error or like in your case some values will be undefined when imported. I would suggest moving shared code to a separate file.

Comment: ya... I had a feeling that might be the fix.  Any suggestions for naming conventions of the shared file?

Comment: I am not familiar with TypeScript and best practices of the TS community, but I would move interfaces in a separate file (maybe one interface per file, but please check what TS documentation suggests). I am also not sure about the purpose of  `sharedFunction1`, so I have no idea how to call the file for it.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov FYI that did fix it; must be an issue with ts-jest (https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest).  Feel free to submit an answer and I will accept it.  

`sharedFunction1` would be what the redux documentation would call a "case function" https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/SplittingReducerLogic.html.  

I'll just go with something generic for now.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and As mentioned by @michael-radionov above in the comments section this was a circular import, and I utilized [circular-dependency-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin) plugin to track these circular imports, more info about plugin usage can be found on the plugin repo or in the following [article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/06/25/circular-dependencies-javascript/)